# woocomerce - admin is not received any email when order is placed

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

I have set all parameters in woocomerce -> settings-> email-> new order , processing etc but email is not sended to admin or email id which i have provided in these option. Yes, email is sending to customer which has purchase items of site. Means email is working for customer but not for admin.. I have tried to change status of order but still mail is sended to customer but not admin. Can you help me to get out of this.
Thanks

Comment: Is the message being sent to spam?

Comment: are you tried by deactivate other plugins except woocommerce?

Answer (score 0):

Try deactivating all other plugins besides WooCommerce to see if that helps. WooCommerce uses the [wp_mail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail) provided by WordPress. As long as other emails are sent, this one should be sent.

A few things to look for:

1. Make sure New Order emails are enabled in WooCommerce > Settings > Emails > New Order.
2. Be sure the order is not placed on *Pending Order*. Keep in mind those emails are not sent to you since the order hasn't been completed yet thus no email.
3. A spam blocker might be the cause of the issue. The best way to avoid this try a dedicated SMTP provider like [Mandrill](http://mandrill.com) which resolves most issues with emails not sending from the host. [Mandrill has a free plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpmandrill/).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Is it the WordPress admin email? I've just had this problem on version 4.1; i was not able to use the wordpress admin email as recipient of emails from new orders; but any other email i set for recipient when new orders worked just fine; all except the wordPress admin email. Weird hu? I guess i'll have to deal with that later.